# How to include a php class in Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I have a directory structure like this:

```
code/folder/theme/includingfile.theme.inc
code/folder/myclass.class.php
```

Inside of myclass.class.php I have a class called DiffName

I've tried using

```
module_load_include('php','DiffName','../myclass.class.php');
```

I've also tried:

```
module_load_include('php','DiffName','../myclass.class');
```

Inside of includingfile.theme.inc, but I still keep getting this error:

```
class DiffName could not be found in code/folder/theme/includingfile.theme.inc
```

The requirements are that the path has to be relative?
Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try adding like module_load_include('php', 'DiffName', 'code/folder/myclass.class');

Answer (score 4):

Drupal has a built-in class loader, you need to provide the location of the files containing classes in your .info file.

https://www.drupal.org/node/542202#files

In your case, that would be

```
files[] = myclass.class.php
```

After flushing your caches (each time you edit .info file), no need of `module_load_include()`, just call `new DiffName();`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. If you want to use module load you have to do you can only load "Modules". If your directory structure looks Like this:

```
sites/all/modules/custom/mymodule/theme/includingfile.theme.inc
sites/all/modules/custom/mymodule/myclass.class.php
```

You need this in includingfile.theme.inc:

```
module_load_include('php','mymodule','../myclass.class');
```